# How can I asynchronously add to my array and wait for completion?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I'm trying to asynchronously add items to my array, and when the array is completed, it would then continue the code. I've had trouble seeing how I could implement promises because the array doesn't start off fully established.

I was at first thinking that I could perhaps wait for a piece of the table to exist before continuing the function, but then it still has to wait for that one to complete.

```
async function getListFact() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfPlaces.length; i++) {
    placeCell = await resolveList(arrayOfPlaces[i], i)
    placeData.push(
      placeCell
    )

    console.log(placeCell)
    if (placeData) { // I left this as just placeData, but I need to wait 
//for all objects in the array to be completed before it reaches past here.
          placeData.sort(function (knit1, pearl2) {
          if (Number(knit1.valuePlayers) > Number(pearl2.valuePlayers)) 
return -1;
         if (Number(knit1.valuePlayers) < Number(pearl2.valuePlayers)) 
 return 1;
       });
       return placeData
     }
   }  
 }
```

I need it to asynchronously push data into the array so it can be done quickly, and then I need it to, after all of the data is in the array, sort the array numerically and then return the data to what called it.

Comment: process the placeData outside the for loop - it'll be all done by then ... `I've had trouble seeing how I could implement promises` ... you're using async/await therefore you ARE using promises ... does `resolveList` return a Promise?

Comment: It starts with this being called: var placeListData = await getListFact() which is the function shown above. resolveList is badly named, but resolveList is a request getting the information needed for placing the object inside of placeData. The objective is to return placeData (the full array) to be rendered.

Comment: yes, that's why I said the `if (placeData) {` should be OUTSIDE the for loop, so you  `await` all calls to `resolveList` ... - again, I ask, does `resolveList` return a Promise that resolves to the required `placeCell` data - if so, then the only thing you need to do (to re-iterate what I've said twice so far) is to move the `if (placeData) {` code AFTER the end of the for loop

Comment: Ah, I get what you're saying now, I apologize. I'm a bit new to web design and this type of coding. So place it outside of the loop so the loop completes first. Although forgive me for asking, but since it's asynchronous, does it wait for the information in the loop to finish? resolveList returns: return {valuePlayers: playing, valuePlaceName: placeTitle, valuePlaceLink: placeLink, valueIcon: placeIcon} // which is to be added to the table individually. That said, no I assume?

Comment: see answer - I make no assumptions about what `resolveList` returns, except to assume it returns a Promise, since your code `await`s on it

Answer (score 0):

the issue with your code seems to be mainly `}` in the wrong places!

This is your code, with an indentation of 4 characters to make it more obvious, and tidied up a bit - but is **exactly** the code you posted in function

```
async function getListFact() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfPlaces.length; i++) {
        placeCell = await resolveList(arrayOfPlaces[i], i)
        placeData.push(placeCell)
        console.log(placeCell)
        if (placeData) {
            placeData.sort(function (knit1, pearl2) {
                if (Number(knit1.valuePlayers) > Number(pearl2.valuePlayers)) return -1;
                if (Number(knit1.valuePlayers) < Number(pearl2.valuePlayers)) return 1;
            });
            return placeData
        } // 1
    } // 2
}
```

Your code will get the first placeCell, push it in placeData, sort this array (with a single element) and return placeData ... so, only the first arrayOfPlaces element will ever be processed

Now, see those `}` marked `1` and `2`

Watch, all I did was move them

```
async function getListFact() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfPlaces.length; i++) {
        placeCell = await resolveList(arrayOfPlaces[i], i);
        placeData.push(placeCell);
        console.log(placeCell);
    } // 2
    if (placeData) {
        placeData.sort(function (knit1, pearl2) {
            if (Number(knit1.valuePlayers) > Number(pearl2.valuePlayers)) return -1;
            if (Number(knit1.valuePlayers) < Number(pearl2.valuePlayers)) return 1;
            return 0; //+ should return 0 when equal
        });
    } // 1
    return placeData;
}
```

Now this code will wait for the loop to finish before sorting and returning placeData - note the additional `return 0` in the sort callback

Also note: `getListFact` returns a `PROMISE` that resolves to the array `placeData` - is this what your calling code expects? A promise?

One other thing, since `placeData` is an array, `if (placeData) {` will always be true - so instead of

```
if (placeData) {
```

I would use

```
if (placeData.length > 1) {
```

Also

```
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfPlaces.length; i++) {
        placeCell = await resolveList(arrayOfPlaces[i], i);
        placeData.push(placeCell);
        console.log(placeCell);
    }
```

can be rewritten as

```
placeData.push(... await Promise.all(arrayOfPlaces.map(resolveList)));
```

> Yet another NOTE: Your code as you wrote it uses "external" variables, `arrayOfPlaces` and `placeData`. If you call the function `getListFact` twice without changing `placeData`, the second call will ADD to the existsing `placeData` array - not sure this is by design (no comment on this design as it may be what you need), or perhaps you're clearing `placeData` before calling `getListFact` (which would be, in my opinion, poor code design) - but as no code outside this function is even described, let alone shown, the code in this answer assumes you know what you want

Comment: The calling code expects an array. I should make it expect a promise instead, then?

Comment: well, of course ... an `async` function ALWAYS returns a Promise - that's how async/await works

Comment: Thank you, I'll fix that now.

Comment: Unfortunately I clear the array each time because everytime the page is loaded it should update the results of what is on the array. The array has the amount of players, the name of a place, the icon of a place, and the link of the place. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: without seeing code I can't see I can't make a judgement

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `Promise.all`. Essentially create a list of tasks you want to do and then wait until all are done.

```js
const arrayOfPlaces = ['US', 'Bills shack', 'Down the road', 'My neighbor', 'Europe'];

async function getListFact() {
  const resolvePlace = place => Promise.resolve(place); // Simulate an async task

  const promises = arrayOfPlaces.map(resolvePlace);
  const placeCells = await Promise.all(promises); // wait until everything is resolved

  console.log(placeCells);
}

getListFact();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
async function getListFact() {
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfPlaces.length; i++) {
    placeData.push(resolveList(arrayOfPlaces[i], i));
  }

  placeData = await Promise.all(placeData);


  placeData.sort(function (knit1, pearl2) {
    if (Number(knit1.valuePlayers) > Number(pearl2.valuePlayers))
      return -1;
    if (Number(knit1.valuePlayers) < Number(pearl2.valuePlayers))
      return 1;

    return 0;
  });

  return placeData;
}
```